# How to use dialog-form jquery for list of buttons in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a list in the javascript, which i'm displaying it in the table format using for loop along with the edit button for each row. When i click on the edit button i need to open the dialog pop-up using jquery dialog. In my code, when i click on the edit button i'm neither getting any error nor the pop up is displaying. What might be the issue. below is my code.

```
$.ajax({

            url : '/edsWeb/getEdsLogData',
            type : 'get',
            dataType : 'json',
            data :  {dc: dc, mdc:mdc, group:group},
            success : function(map) {
                console.log(map);

            var htmlStr = "<table border='1'>";
                htmlStr += "<tr> <td>User Name </td> <td> User Group </td> <td> Remarks </td>";
                htmlStr += " <td> Edit User remarks</td></tr>";
                for (var i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
                     htmlStr += "<tr><td>";
                     htmlStr +=  map[i].userName;
                     htmlStr += "</td><td>";
                     htmlStr +=  map[i].userGroup;
                     htmlStr += "</td><td>";
                     htmlStr +=  map[i].userRemarks;
                     htmlStr += "</td><td>";
                     htmlStr += " <button id='editRemarkId"+i+"'> Edit </button>";
                     htmlStr += "</td></tr>";
                }
                htmlStr += "</table>"
                $out = $('#em_Ordering');
                $out.html(htmlStr);



                },
            error : function() {
                alert("error occured!!!");
            },

        });
```

Dialog script code:

```
$(function() {


$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
autoOpen: false,
height: 300,
width: 350,
modal: true,
buttons: {
"Update Remarks": function() {

},
Cancel: function() {
$( this ).dialog( "close" );
}
},

});
$( "#editRemarkId" )
.button()
.click(function() {
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done small changes in the code,now it is working.just look at this
http://jsfiddle.net/nZLeU/
Need to add these 4 files to get jquery dialog

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
```

If you want anything just check this link
[Jquerydialogue](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)